# SQL performance - Filtering on query before or after unions

Tags: c#, query-performance

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT PersonId,
       Note,
       Amount
FROM Table1 A
WHERE A.PersonId = @PersonId

UNION 

SELECT PersonId,
       Note,
       Amount
FROM Table2 B
WHERE B.PersonId = @PersonId

UNION 

SELECT PersonId,
       Note,
       Amount
FROM Table3 C
WHERE C.PersonId = @PersonId
```

Now, this query will eventually return thousands of results and so I want to build the best performing query possible. I want to know if that's more efficient than filtering on PersonId after the unions such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT PersonId,
       Note,
       Amount
FROM Table1 A

UNION 

SELECT PersonId,
       Note,
       Amount
FROM Table2 B

UNION 

SELECT PersonId,
       Note,
       Amount
FROM Table3 C
) A
WHERE A.PersonId = @PersonId
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all you will have a query optimizer.
There will be no difference in speed, because the PersonId is on the display layer.
The query optimizer will change the execution order of the display parameters so that there will be a minimal amount of parameters.
So both queries will be equal at speed.
If you are interested, you can see this execution plan in your SQL developer.

Comment: Would it be the same with joins? Joining on each query as opposed to at the end ?

Comment: Try it yourself in your sql developer. Compare both and you will have your result. As far as I think joins could be faster. I think the query optimizer will reconstruct your union query to a join query. So it would be faster with joins. But  why is you PersonID not a primary key?